# Veryfing if an elment is present in a non-editable page

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to verify if an element is present or not in a non editable page or not. This is my html file:

```
<select name="sys_readonly.req_item.state" aria-readonly="true" aria-disabled="true" id="sys_readonly.sc_req_item.state"><option value="1" selected="SELECTED" role="option" disabled="disabled">Open</option><option value="2" role="option" disabled="disabled">Work in Progress</option></select>
```

I am trying to verify that that the select name="sys_readonly.req_item.state" has the option "open". This is what I have done till now:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(
                ExpectedConditions.or(
                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("sys_readonly.req_item.state")))
                )
            );
    Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(
                ExpectedConditions.or(
                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("sys_readonly.req_item.state")))
                )
            );
    Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("sys_readonly.req_item.state")));   

     WebElement o = droplist.getFirstSelectedOption();
     String selectedoption = o.getText();
     System.out.println("Selected element: " + selectedoption);
```

I am getting the error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"css selector","selector":"#sys_readonly.req_item.state"}

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://walmartglobalcert.service-now.com/navpage.do

Comment: Unfortunately not able to access

Answer (score 0):

**As per the HTML given by you, the id used is incorrect:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sys_readonly.req_item.state"));
```

[image]

**Try to use:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sys_readonly.sc_req_item.state']"));
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sys_readonly.sc_req_item.state"));
```

**I have tried to use the code and got the below result:**

**Code:**

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.name("sys_readonly.req_item.state"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele));
        Select droplist = new Select(ele);
        WebElement o = droplist.getFirstSelectedOption();
        String selectedoption = o.getText();
        System.out.println("Selected element: " + selectedoption);

        for (WebElement selectList : droplist.getAllSelectedOptions()) {
            System.out.println(selectList.getText());
        }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. You are using a wrong locator. `sys_readonly.req_item.state` is the element `name` attribute value, not `id`.
2. You are asking about element presence but validating it's visibility. These are not the same. Element can be presented (existing) on the page, but not be visible.
   So, you can get the element and then extract it `option` attribute and validate if `open` value is existing there

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("sys_readonly.req_item.state")));
String option_val = driver.findElement(By.name("sys_readonly.req_item.state"))..getAttribute(option);
Assert.assertTrue(option_val.contains("open"));
```